# Client side validation of a non mandatory integer field with minimum value 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I want to do client side validation of an integer field in my Dto making it non mandatory as well as setting it's minimum value as 1

I have tried @Min annotation but nothing is assured for default 0 value which is making the validation fail when validity field is null

```
@Min(value=1)
private int validity;
```

I know the work-around is to do the validation server side but I want to do the validation client-side itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my requirement. If I replace int by String than I can take null as a valid argument.

```
@Min(value=1)
private String validity;
```

With above code comes some validation on using parsing String to int while storing the value

```
if(isValidDtoString(validity))
    int validity = Integer.parseInt(validity);
public static boolean isValidDtoString(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Better replace int with Integer, not with String.